# reply_markup does not work in php + webhook

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I simply don't understand why the first block works, and the second not.

I'm using altervista free hosting.

```
$url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?   //This works
chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($msg)."&parseMode=HTML";
file_get_contents($url);
```

It works for sending messages.
If i add this line it just does nothing:

```
$keyboard = ('&reply_markup={"keyboard ":[["READ"],["Developer"]]}');
//$key2 = ('&reply_markup={"keyboard \":[[\"READ\"],[\"Developer\"]]}');

$url2 = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=zzz".$keyboard;
file_get_contents($url2); //does nothing
```

after i encoded with urlencoder it sends the message, but does not change the keyboard.

The bot does not change the keyboard. I would like to change the keyboard

Comment: You are creating JSON by hand and URLs by hand. Neither of these are good ideas. Use `json_encode()` and `http_build_query()`.

Comment: try:    $keyboard = ('&reply_markup={"[keyboard ":[["READ"],["Developer"]]]}');